# Getting 400 Bad Request Error in Post Request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

I am recording a script through blazemeter for a Banking App, Frontend is showing the transaction status as successful but in Jmeter that particular request is failing, That is a post request in which all data is passing to the server for transaction.

Screenshots attached below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ghD9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd0Mv.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting **expected** [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) 400 and would like JMeter to not to fail this request:

1. Add [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) as a child of the request
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, this way JMeter will treat the parent [HTTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) with response status code 400 as successful.

Comment: Its a payment request, Transaction is being processed successfully at Frontend but getting failed in Jmeter.

Comment: Knowing this is a payment request there is a chance that some parameter have to be changed for each new call. for ex. there could be a session id you pass through cookies / header. Please check with your developer with the reference of contextid and code from the response.